# Separate Service and Business layers in ASP MVC app architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture, n-tier-architecture

last few days i'm reading alot about apps architecture as i prepare myself for new project.
So far, i pretty much used architecture like:

Presentation layer (ASP MVC controllers)
Business layer [using domain model]
Repository

Those use depencency injection with composition root.

As i read last days, I've found quite a few resources that suggest having something like:

Presentation layer
Service layer
Business layer
Repository

So, having Service layer in between Presentation and Business. The only thing i can see going in that one is automapper so Service layer would act as an intermediate to prepare input (model) for business layer. If that is the only benefit then i'm not sure i would go with whole new layer for it. I'd sacrifice thin controller story and put automapper into controller if that is the only benefit of Service layer.

So, the question is...is there some other benefits of having Service layer in front of Business one that i'm missing?

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated!
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Service Layer is a thin wrapper over your domain Model(Business). You can use any pattern like Facade for creating Service Layer since Service Layer will be responsible for composing business logic as per your requirements.There are lot many facets to this but if you are having simple CRUD application, this will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your input!
It's not a simple CRUD application. On the other hand, it's non-distributed deployment strategy. If it was a distributed one then i'd see a clear advantage, of course, because in that case Service layer might be exposed via WCF e.g. to outer world. But in case of non-distributed one i still see no advantage in having it.

Comment: service layer I am referring to is "Domain Service Layer" from Domain driven design and not the services in distributed systems. Now, if you do not use domain service layer and directly expose your domain model, your domain model will eventually will be corrupt and will end up in anemic model. Please go through domain driven design to understand the concepts of domain model and anemic domain model.